# Docker tag: use / as part of docker tag

Tags: docker

I would like to use `/` as part of my docker tag - for example, something/something:mytag/123

Is this possible or only `.` `-` and `_` are allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Docker Tag Naming Rules:**

A Docker tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain:
 - Lowercase and Uppercase letters
 - Digits
 - Underscores
 - Periods
 - Dashes

It also may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.

As a side note, a `/` is only used in a tag when it is preceded by a registry name or repository name.

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/)